# How to organize repeating code?

Tags: c#

The code looks as following:

1) I have some images:

```
var imageIds = caseStudyPage.Images;
foreach (var imageId in imageIds)
{
    byte[] csImage = GetImage(imageId);
}
```

2) And I have the structure as following:

```
var document = new Document();
document
    .AddField(new TextField("CS Counter Basic Name", "Case Study"))
    .AddField(new TextField("CS Counter Number", _numberInParentDocument.ToString()))
    .AddField(new TextField("Page Title", caseStudyPage.Page_Title))
    .AddField(new TextField("Common Footer Text 1", commonFooterText1))
    .AddField(new TextField("Page Title Content", caseStudyPage.Page_Title))
    .AddTable(new Table("Images")
        .AddRow(new TableRow().AddField(new ImageField("Image", imageBytes, ImageType.Jpeg))
            .AddField(new TextField("Overview", caseStudyPage.Overview))
            .AddField(new TextField("Engagement", caseStudyPage.Engagement))
            .AddField(new TextField("Publish Date", caseStudyPage.Publish_Date.ToString("MMM. dd, yyyy")))
    .AddField(new TextField("Common Footer Text 2", commonFooterText2))));
```

I need to put document structure from 2) inside the loop from 1) in order to set imageBytes variable of ImageField, but document should be only one. I'm not sure how to loop only this part:

```
.AddRow(new TableRow().AddField(new ImageField("Image", imageBytes, ImageType.Jpeg))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var document = new Document();
document
    .AddField(new TextField("CS Counter Basic Name", "Case Study"))
    .AddField(new TextField("CS Counter Number", _numberInParentDocument.ToString()))
    .AddField(new TextField("Page Title", caseStudyPage.Page_Title))
    .AddField(new TextField("Common Footer Text 1", commonFooterText1))
    .AddField(new TextField("Page Title Content", caseStudyPage.Page_Title));

var table = new Table("Images");
foreach (var imageId in imageIds)
{
    byte[] csImage = GetImage(imageId);
    table.AddRow(new TableRow().AddField(new ImageField("Image", csImage, ImageType.Jpeg))
            .AddField(new TextField("Overview", caseStudyPage.Overview))
            .AddField(new TextField("Engagement", caseStudyPage.Engagement))
            .AddField(new TextField("Publish Date", caseStudyPage.Publish_Date.ToString("MMM. dd, yyyy")));
}

document.AddTable(table);
document.AddField(new TextField("Common Footer Text 2", commonFooterText2))));
```

Comment: There's an error:

Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1061 'Document' does not contain a definition for 'AddRow' and no extension method 'AddRow' accepting a first argument of type 'Document' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) EPAM.Lookbook.Sitecore C:\Projects\epm-lkbk\src\EPAM.Lookbook.Sitecore\CMS\PDF\NewPdfBuilder.cs 193 Active

Comment: I've found the solution:

IEnumerable<Table> tables = document.Tables;
tables.ElementAt(0).AddRow(new TableRow().AddField(new ImageField("Image", csImage, ImageType.Jpeg))